# How to print duplex with winspool.drv in golang

Tags: windows, go, printing

I needed basic printing functionality to print PDFs at variable page sizes. I was able to get this to work with the following code I just posted [here](https://github.com/jadefox10200/goprint/blob/master/main.go).
However, trying to access the printer options to get PDFs to print duplex seems very complicated.

Is there a simple way to get these PDFs to print duplex?

Comment: Am I correct that by "print duplex" you mean "two pages on the same side of a single sheet of paper" (also known as "booklet")? Or maybe "print on each side of each sheet" (as opposed to keeping each other side of each sheet blank)?

Comment: If the PDF has two pages in it, each page prints on an individual piece of paper currently. Therefore, I want to print page 1 on the front and page 2 on the back of a single piece of paper. In my case, I am printing either legal or letter size sheets. Does that clarify it?

Comment: I'm starting to believe that no one has actually done this in golang. At this point I will have to explore using cgo which is disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

Just come across this.  I'm not sure what you are doing is possible without something to render the PDF in windows and then print it.

What you are doing (I think) is sending a PDF directly to a printer that supports printing PDFs directly - not all printers do.

This means that no commands for printer options are sent with it and it bypasses the windows print drivers, you could try prepending some PJL (Printer Job Language)commands to the beginning of the PDF that you send.

If you can't get that to work or control what you need, then you'll need to have something render the PDF and print it in conjunction with the printer drivers into a native printer language such as PCL or Postscript.  Printing in windows usually involves the graphics device interface (GDI) or WPF working with the installed printer driver for your printer.  This route should give you access to all printer driver options for your printer.

Comment: I agree with you. In the end because I was unable to figure out the rendering in GO I switched off of windows and went to linux. CUPS in linux has a lot of support for printing and can accept commands so was able to simply use the EXEC package to do this. Kind of a hassle but in the end switching to a linux server made this possible and able to control duplex, stapling and variable page sizes.